# Why sylow $ p $-subgroups of $ H $ are Sylow $ p $-subgroups of $ G $?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $ H $ is a subgroup of $ G $ that $ \vert G : H \vert $ is a $ \pi $-number and there exist a nilpotent subgroup $ K $ of $ G $ that $ G = HK $.then we can let $ K = K_{\pi}K_{\pi^{\prime}}$, that $ K_{\pi} $ is a $ \pi $-Hall subgroup of $ K $ and $ K_{\pi^{\prime}} $ is a $ \pi^{\prime} $-Hall subgroup of $ K $. let $ K_{\pi^{\prime}} > 1 $ and $ K_{p} $ is a nonidentity sylow $ p $-subgroup of $ K_{\pi^{\prime}} $. Why sylow $ p $-subgroups of $ H $ are Sylow $ p $-subgroups of $ G $?

Comment: Because $|G:H|$ is a $\pi$-number and $p \in \pi'$.

Comment: can you explain further?

Comment: If $P \in Syl_p(H)$, then $index[H:P]$ is not divisible by $p$. Since $index[G:H] \in \pi$ and $p \in \pi'$, $index[G:P]=index[G:H] \cdot index[H:P]$ is not divisible by $p$. So $P \in Syl_p(G)$.